# Exception in orchard when adding new Widget

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I am creating a new Calendar Widget in Orchard. I added the driver, handler, models and Editor View.
Now, I go to Widgets, Add Widget, Select the Calendar Widget, I get the following exception:

```
2014-07-15 13:58:02,972 [20] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - Default - An unexpected exception was caught
http://localhost/Orchard/Admin/Widgets/AddWidget?layerId=3&widgetType=CalendarWidget&zone=Content&returnUrl=%2FOrchard%2FAdmin%2FWidgets
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentCreateExtensions.New[T](IContentManager manager, String contentType) in c:\Workspaces\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\ContentExtensions.cs:line 21
   at Orchard.Widgets.Controllers.AdminController.AddWidget(Int32 layerId, String widgetType, String zone, String returnUrl) in c:\Workspaces\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.Widgets\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 151
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41()
2014-07-15 13:59:32,478 [5] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - Default - An unexpected exception was caught
```

Where shall I be looking first?

Thanks

Comment: Show your migration: you probably forgot to add the Common part, the Widget part, or the Widget stereotype.

Comment: Hi Bertrand, I had to create the Table for the Part in the Database. It then worked! I thought with Infoset, no need to create a Table for the part.

Comment: That's correct: if you work with infoset, there is no need to create a table for the part. Show your part.

Comment: This is the part class: 

`public class CalendarWidgetPart : ContentPart<CalendarWidgetPartRecord>
    {
        public int QueryId {
            get { return Retrieve(x => x.QueryId); }
            set { Store(x => x.QueryId, value); }
        }
    }`

Comment: Right, if you want to use the Infoset, just get rid of your record class.